# Help me out VS Help me

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-usage

I don't understand the difference between the following two sentences and grammatical explanation. Why we use *out* here and also here "**Ask her out for a dance.**
Thanks.

1. **Help him**
2. **Help him out**

Comment: To **ask someone out** has the particular meaning of 'invite them to attend a social event or entertainment with you, usually with romantic intentions' - **out** because you are going somewhere outside the home.

Comment: ask her out has zero to do with your question. Please edit it.

Answer (score 1):

"Ask out" is an idiomatic term for asking someone on a date. "Help out" is also idiomatic, but they are not related. The 'out' in "ask out" means to *go out(side)*, to go somewhere on a date.

"Help out" has more in common with "work out", which can mean to *solve* a problem. "Help out" means that you contribute to achieving something.

For example, if you "help out with the dishes" that would mean you work alongside someone else to do the dishes. However, if you helped out *by* doing the dishes, it could mean that you do the dishes alone but that helps achieve some other overall goal such as cleaning the entire kitchen.

Answer (score 0):

**To help someone** is to provide assistance in what could be a dangerous or difficult situation.

**To help someone out is slightly less heavy.**

- You help someone who is having a heart attack by performing CPR.
- You help out your neighbor by cutting his grass if his leg is in a cast.
- You help out in the kitchen when your actual job is greeting people when they enter the restaurant.

Comment: But **help** doesn't necessarily imply danger or difficulty. It can be used in any context, while **help out** usually refers to helping someone to carry out a task.

Comment: @KateBunting I believe I said: in what **could be**. If I help you with your homework, the situation is difficult for you. I am **contrasting** help and help out and not defining every single usage of the verb help.